# css3 animation keyframes timing only work in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, cross-browser, keyframe

I've just created a preloader animation using css3 and it only works properly on Chrome... on all the other browsers, the animation IS working, but the timing for the bar in the middle is late, screwing the whole timing for the animation... I can't understand why, because all the keyframes are carefully set... any thoughts?

here's the animation on Fiddle and the code: http://jsfiddle.net/chevalier/ygo2ebxo/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="bar1gray">
    <div id="bar1gray_1" class="bar1red"></div>        
</div>
<div id="bar2gray">
    <div id="bar2gray_1" class="bar2red"></div>        
</div>
<div id="bar3gray">
    <div id="bar3gray_1" class="bar3red"></div>        
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #wrapper {
    width:100px; 
    height:100px; 
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}
#bar1gray {
    width:57%; 
    height:15%; 
    background-color:#D2D3D5; 
    transform: skewX(-15.71deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-15.71deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-15.71deg);
    margin-bottom:11px;
    position:absolute; top:16%; left:29%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bar2gray {
    width:49%; 
    height:15%; 
    background-color:#D2D3D5;
    transform: skewX(-15.71deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-15.71deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-15.71deg); 
    margin-bottom:11px; 
    position:absolute; top:42%; left:21%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#bar3gray {
    width:60%; 
    height:15%; 
    background-color:#D2D3D5;
    transform: skewX(-15.71deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-15.71deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-15.71deg);
    position:absolute; top:68%; left:14%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.bar1red {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:#F93725; 

    animation-name:bar1;
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-timing-function:ease;

    -moz-animation-name:bar1;
    -moz-animation-duration:2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -webkit-animation-name:bar1;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -ms-animation-name:bar1;
    -ms-animation-duration:2s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -o-animation-name:bar1;
    -o-animation-duration:2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -o-animation-timing-function:ease;
}
.bar2red {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:#F93725;

    animation-name:bar2;
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-timing-function:ease;
    animation-delay:1.5s;

    -moz-animation-name:bar2;
    -moz-animation-duration:2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -webkit-animation-name:bar2;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -ms-animation-name:bar2;
    -ms-animation-duration:2s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -o-animation-name:bar2;
    -o-animation-duration:2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -o-animation-timing-function:ease;
}
.bar3red {
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background-color:#F93725;

    animation-name:bar3;
    animation-duration:2s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-timing-function:ease;

    -moz-animation-name:bar3;
    -moz-animation-duration:2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -webkit-animation-name:bar3;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -ms-animation-name:bar3;
    -ms-animation-duration:2s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function:ease;

    -o-animation-name:bar3;
    -o-animation-duration:2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -o-animation-timing-function:ease;    
}
/* animation BAR1 */ 
@-moz-keyframes bar1{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    25%{margin-left:0;}
    65%{margin-left:0;}
    90%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bar1{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    25%{margin-left:0;}
    65%{margin-left:0;}
    90%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@-ms-keyframes bar1{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    25%{margin-left:0;}
    65%{margin-left:0;}
    90%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@-o-keyframes bar1{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    25%{margin-left:0;}
    65%{margin-left:0;}
    90%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@keyframes bar1{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    25%{margin-left:0;}
    65%{margin-left:0;}
    90%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}
/* animation BAR2 */ 
@-moz-keyframes bar1{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    5%{margin-left:-100%;}
    30%{margin-left:0;}
    70%{margin-left:0;}
    95%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bar2{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    5%{margin-left:-100%;}
    30%{margin-left:0;}
    70%{margin-left:0;}
    95%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}V
}

@-ms-keyframes bar2{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    5%{margin-left:-100%;}
    30%{margin-left:0;}
    70%{margin-left:0;}
    95%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@-o-keyframes bar2{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    5%{margin-left:-100%;}
    30%{margin-left:0;}
    70%{margin-left:0;}
    95%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@keyframes bar2{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    5%{margin-left:-100%;}
    30%{margin-left:0;}
    70%{margin-left:0;}
    95%{margin-left:100%;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}
/* animation BAR3 */ 
@-moz-keyframes bar3{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    10%{margin-left:-100%;}
    35%{margin-left:0;}
    75%{margin-left:0;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bar3{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    10%{margin-left:-100%;}
    35%{margin-left:0;}
    75%{margin-left:0;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@-ms-keyframes bar3{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    10%{margin-left:-100%;}
    35%{margin-left:0;}
    75%{margin-left:0;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@-o-keyframes bar3{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    10%{margin-left:-100%;}
    35%{margin-left:0;}
    75%{margin-left:0;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}

@keyframes bar3{
    0%{margin-left:-100%;}
    10%{margin-left:-100%;}
    35%{margin-left:0;}
    75%{margin-left:0;}
    100%{margin-left:100%;}
}
```

tks! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ygo2ebxo/7/

Is this working for you in all the browser?

You will have to remove the below line from the class .bar2red:

```
animation-delay:1.5s;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: tks, man! you're a life saver... I didn't notice that I'd forgotten that line over there! ;)